# How to integrate a wildcard operator * to math auth routes

Tags: string, go

I am building a authentication system in go and so far i am verry pleased with the working of it. But now i want to integrate a wildcard operator like the following:

if the uri is /user/list and in the allowed map there is /user/* it must pas.

```
Allowed {
  "*": {"administrator", "regional"}, // logic works
  "/user/*": {"administrator"}, // how to implement
  "/login": {"administrator", "regional"}, // logic works
}

func (a *Authentication) IsAllowed(req *http.Request, role string) error {
schema := a.Schema // = the Allowed map[string][]string above
url := req.URL.String()

// Check strict match of the url in the schema
roles, ok := schema[url] 
if ok {
  if util.InSlice(role, roles) {
    return nil
  } else {
    return USERNOTALLOWED // error
  }
}

// here must come the logic of the wildcardsuffix
if a.hasWildCardSuffix(url string) {

}

// Fallback to wildCard *
if a.hasWildCard() { // return a bool whenever there is a "*" key
  roles, _ = a.Schema["*"] 
  if util.InSlice(role, roles) {
    return nil
  } else {
    return USERNOTALLOWED // error
  }
 }
 return nil
}
```

thx alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filepath has a [Match](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match) function can do this for you:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {   
    ok, err := filepath.Match("/user/*", "/user/list")
    log.Print(err)
    log.Print(ok)
    ok, err = filepath.Match("/user/*/*", "/user/list/detail")
    log.Print(err)
    log.Print(ok)
}
```

playground: http://play.golang.org/p/DZ2yVmi5zs

Comment: fails on longer routes like /user/list/create

Comment: @user3396016 use this: /user/*/*